# Regularization in Feed-forward Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have just gone through some on-line open course lectures by Andrew Ng in Coursera. At the end of the lectures regarding Neural Networks, he explained reguralization but I am afraid I missed something. With reguralization, the value of cost function is calculated as follows:

`J(theta) = -1/m * jValMain + lambda/(2*m)*JValReg`

`jValMain` is set of sums to over `y`, and output of NN. The second component `jValReg` is to apply reguralization and looks something like this:

`jValReg = lambda/(2*m)*sum( sum( sum( Theta(j)(i)(k)^2 ) ) )`

`Theta` is a set of weights, `m` is a number of all elements/cases in database and then the `lambda`. What is lambda? Is it scalar or vector or matrix? How do we apply reguralization via lambda? Is lambda to regulate a particular jth and ith weight from lth layer or is it to regulate all weights by one number. It somehow confuses me. If anyone is familiar with this concept, I will be grateful for any help.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` is the regularization parameter in your estimation. Think of it as a means to control the bias in your estimate. It is a scalar and is often used to prevent over fitting of the data. Here are a few lines taken from the notes of the coursera assignments.

> ... the value of lambda can significantly affect the results of regularized polynomial regression on the training and cross validation set. In particular, a model without regularization (lambda = 0) fits the training set well, but does not generalize. Conversely, a model with too much regularization (lambda = 100) does not fit the training set and testing set well. A good choice of lambda (e.g., lambda = 1) can provide a good fit to the data.